# How to use git kraken for a force push

Tags: git, git-push, git-gui, gitkraken

I'm using git kraken client gui and I need to perform a force push on a repository. It would be really grateful if someone can guide me the steps to perform a force push on git kraken.

Comment: Doesn't it give you the option when you try to push?

Comment: Nope. This should definitely be a thing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Viktor Seč commented: When you hit push and GitKraken detects that a fast forward update is not possible, it lets you decide wether you want to pull (i.e. merge) changes from upstream or perform a force push:

[image: GitKraken Pull or Force Push]

If this is not shown, then a force push is not necessary and a normal, fast-forward update can be performed.

Comment: I wish there were a force push button somewhere for when I already know a force push is required (like after a rebase). I have a git hook on push and right now it runs twice: once before and once after the prompt to pull or force push... :'(